# creating objects using array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have array of data , and base of that I would like to create as many objects as the array have:

I'm trying to do it with foreach loop, but cant crack it.

```
 foreach($file->data as $item){
         $entity = new MappedEntity($file,$counter++);
     }
```

it's working but for example array length =5 , It's overriding the value 5 times and as result I'm having one object with values from fifth record, and I would like to create 5 objects with corresponding properties.

Im total newbie to PHP , any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite a weird way to behave, but before further knowledge, you can create 5 instances of your class like this:

```
$i = 1;

foreach ($file->data as $item) {
  ${"entity_" . $i} = new MappedEntity($file, $counter++);
  $i++;
}

//now you have class instances in variables $entity_1, $entity_2 etc...
```

Or you can store instances to array like this ( preferred way to do this ):

```
$arr = [];

foreach ($file->data as $item) {
  $arr[] = new MappedEntity($file, $counter++);
}

// now you have array with 5 class instances and you can access them with $arr[0], $arr[1] etc...
```

Comment: I would not recommend doing method #1. It makes a ton of variables and becomes very difficult to manage. Worse, there's no easy way to iterate over it

Comment: Im doing method 2

Comment: @Machavity Totally agree.

Comment: @filemonczyk Please accept answer, if it was helpful.

Comment: and to acces the object in this array and it's methods I must somehow cast a type on it? because $entities[0]-> is not working

Comment: @filemonczyk You should be able to access object method by calling $arr[0]->someMethod()

Comment: damn I had no pop-up from my ide and tought something is wrong, but it's just not popup ................ ARGH